# Create XCFramework with multiple framworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am first time trying to create a XCFramework with below command.

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework ./Logger-iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Logger.framework \
-framework ./Logger-Sim.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Logger.framework \
-output ./Logger.xcframework
```

This command is able to generate a XCFramework. But my question here is, in the Logger-IOS.xcarchive and Logger-Sim.xcarchive contains multiple frameworks(please refer to below images). So, how should I include all the frameworks in to the XCframework? Or should I generate seperate XCframeworks for each .framework? as per the above command, I can specify only one framework.

[image]

Contents of Logger-iOS.xcarchive

[image]

Comment: were u able to figure this out?